# how to write if condition for 3 rows at a time in different table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to match the Number columns in below table using model segment and source

[image]

This is the main table where I would like to map Number here using mysql:

[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: are you talking about joins?

Comment: your desired output?

Comment: not about joins i should have to get output in the second table numbers.

Comment: @UmairMubeen if those 3 column are same then we should get the 4th column number in the below table can we use if,Else conditions or any other logic

Comment: from above two tables what will be your expected output.

Comment: @HariKishore in the second table number is the expected output

Answer (score 0):

User join. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    t2.customer_name,
    t1.*
FROM
    table2 as t2
left join table1 as t1 on
    t1.model = t2.model
    and t1.segment = t2.segment
    and t1.source = t2.source
```